# Mvc application(from default) user registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I make a Mvc4 application from defaults I've been given at the beginning.

I need to store the modified UserProfile in my DB, so I have changed the UserProfile class for  fulfilling my needs and also changed the RegisterModel class. Now when I register someone, I have a correct view with all the necessary fields for it, however, when I open Server Explorer for check, I get a UserProfile table with UserId and UserName only(but by the model there should also be firstname,lastname,email and so on).

What should be modified more for storing them correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same spot a few months ago. One of the issues is that the registration story isn't exactly completed out of the box. For example, if someone register first THEN link their external account, they can wind up with multiple profiles.

I pull the user id from the webpages_OAuthMembership table on successful login.

if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: true))
            {

```
            var oAuthMembership = new EndeavorODataEntities().webpages_OAuthMembership
                .Where(u => u.ProviderUserId == result.ProviderUserId)
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Provider == result.Provider) ?? 
                new webpages_OAuthMembership
                        {
                            Provider = result.Provider,
                            ProviderUserId = result.ProviderUserId,
                        };

            TempData.Add("OAuthMembership", oAuthMembership);
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("UserId", oAuthMembership.UserId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

            return RedirectToAction("Summary", new { Controller = "Member", id = oAuthMembership.UserId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) });
```

From here, I make a separate call to my custom 'Membership' table on another controller, as I store all of my application data in a separate db from the this OAuthMember table. In my prior experience in using the ASP.NET Membership provider database, I always kept that as a separate db from my applications, reusing it across multiple apps. Of course, if you wished to modify the UserProfile or other tables, as you can see from the code above, this is just a LINQ statement. There is nothing to say you couldn't perform a join to the UserProfiles table here too.

In this example above I had created an edmx file OAuthMembership.edmx and imported my tables from SQL just like any other database. EndeavorODataEntities is the name of my connection string, and webpages_OAuthMembership is the name of the actual membership table.

I've added in some other resources that I've used which may help you.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/22/extra-information-from-oauth-openid-provider.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranav_rastogi/archive/2012/08/23/plugging-custom-oauth-openid-providers.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/24/customizing-the-login-ui-when-using-oauth-openid.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/09/12/integrate-openauth-openid-with-your-existing-asp-net-application-using-universal-providers.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/09/19/configuring-your-asp-net-application-for-microsoft-oauth-account.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/15/initializesimplemembership-attribute-and-simplemembership-exceptions.aspx

Comment: This is my first app, so I would like to keep it simple. I edited the connection for my local DB right now, so I would like to store the products and users there. And I got into a mess a little. Should I edit the code in ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback and put yours there? And what does EndeavorODataEntities() and webpages_OAuthMembership mean?

Comment: Putting the code in the ActionResult (or in a separate private method called from the ActionResult) on the controller is perfectly fine, so yes put it there. There's no harm in putting all of your tables in the same DB, especially if this is your first application. see expanded answer above for more details.